# Sending files from server to client

Tags: ssh, terminal, file-transfer

I know there are ways to copy files from the client side to and from the server, but is there away that the server can automatically send a file every x amount of minutes to the a specific computer on a different network.

Comment: When two computers connect, the one that initiated the connection is usually called the "client" and the other one the "server". What do you mean by having "the server" send a file? How is this different from the normal client/server file copying that you say you already know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest writing and running a script in some programming language to do this task on your server. It would maintain a TCP connection with a client script and every x minutes the server would send the file to the client where the client would save the file and wait.

Comment: How would i do this with two different networks, my computer isn't on the same network as the server.

Comment: You need the IP-address of your server or client. Then you can tell the other to connect to that IP. If you are unfamiliar with socket programming I recommend reading some tutorials. This application you desire could be pretty quickly done in Java, C++, Python, or most other languages.

Answer (score 0):

For a server to send a file (or anything), there would either have to be an open connection (the client asking for something, basically), or the "client" would have to have a protocol open for the server to connect to (ie ftp), which would make the client a server.